# Calling Google API from localhost

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-custom-search

I am trying to call the Google CSE Api from my localhost Docker container. Apparently, this is not working because of that.

I have defined `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false in order to prevent SSL certificate verification, but with no success.

If anyone has any thought on this, help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
// Create the google api client
$googleClient = new Google_Client();

// Set the google developer api key
$googleClient->setApplicationName('GoogleApi_Search');
$googleClient->setDeveloperKey(self::GOOGLE_SEARCH_API_KEY);

// for development purposes
$guzzleConfig = [
    'curl'    => [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false],
    'headers' => ['Referer' => 'localhost:8080'],
];
$guzzleClient = new Client($guzzleConfig);
$googleClient->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

// The google custom search service client
$this->googleService = new Google_Service_Customsearch($googleClient);

// Define the search parameters
$this->searchParams = [
    'cx'    => self::GOOGLE_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID,   // Custom search engine identifier
    'gl'    => 'en',                            // Location of results
    'lr'    => 'lang_en',                       // Language of results
    'num'   => 10,                              // Number of results (max. 10)
    'start' => 0,                               // The current index (max. 10)
];
```

Comment: "I have defined CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false in order to prevent SSL certificate verification, but with no success." Why? Google's SSL should be perfectly valid whether you're calling it from localhost or elsewhere. What error or specific issue are you having? All you've given us is "this is not working".

Comment: I have an error 400 “Invalid Value”. No other information is returned by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by setting the `start` parameter to **1** instead of **0**. Apparently, setting it to be `0` trigger a *fatal error* on the server side which causes the error **400** `Invalid Value` and no other information.

Strange but working.